# Connect django web app to postgresql in gcloud

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, gcloud

i have been struggling to connect my django web app to a PostgreSQL instance which I set up inside my gcloud account for testing purposes.

I have done the following DB configs in settings.py in Django:

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'instance connection name from gcloud',
        'USER' : 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'passsss',
        'HOST': 'ip-address',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

the error that I receive in Django after trying to migrate is :

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "..instance connection name from gcloud.." does not exist`

I have tried creating a new database "django" and adding it to the NAME with:. This did not work as well. I have also configured in gcloud connections my own computer IP as an authorized network

Normally if I use service like elephantsql it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: where is your django web app running?

Comment: Its running on my local pc

Comment: You can check the official documentation [Connecting to Cloud SQL from external applications](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your post, is that you wish to connect from your local pc to a Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance.

I see that you seem to be following the official documentation already, as you mentioned that you added your IP to authorized networks in order to be able to connect externally.

The cause of your error seems to be due to the format of the NAME parameter.

Are you passing it in this format?

> PROJECT:ZONE:INSTANCENAME

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/external-connection-methods) you have all the available options on how to connect externally to a Cloud PostgreSQL instance.

And [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app) you have the documentation of the requirements to connect an external application to a Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance.

Comment: right, this is the format that i used. From the documentation i decided to connect via external IP. Its less secure but its ok for dev. Additionally, i am also able to connect to the instance from the GUI pgadmin . I believe , my problem is defenitely with Django configs.

Answer (score 0):

ok finally after a lot of research and wasting couple of hours I managed to find Django configs in digital ocean docu... pretty weird

This works:

```
'''
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'my_django_db',
        'USER' : 'user1',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'ipv4',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
'''
```